# How do I pass two values in a onchange function?

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I have an input which id is customer_id and another input is invoice number which id is invoice_no . I have put onchangefunction on invoice number , I have passed invoice_no value in onchange function by writing onchange function but I also want to pass the value of customer_id in this onchange function .. how should I do that ?

```
<input list="customer_id" id="customer_id"  name="customer_id" >


<input type="text" id="invoice_no" onchange="checkinvoice(this.value);"  name="invoice_no" >
```

I want to insert the value of customer_id input with invoice onchange fucntion this.value

Comment: You don't really need to pass that value. Within the `onchange` handler, you can get that value by using `document.getElementById("customer_id").value`.

Comment: I did not understand ?

Answer (score 3):

> I also want to pass the value of customer_id

```
checkinvoice(this.value,document.getElementById('customer_id').value)
```

```js
function checkinvoice(invoice_no, customer_id) {
  console.log('invoice_no', invoice_no, 'customer_id', customer_id);
}
```

```html
<input list="customer_id" id="customer_id" name="customer_id">

<input type="text" id="invoice_no" onchange="checkinvoice(this.value,document.getElementById('customer_id').value);" name="invoice_no">
```

Answer (score 1):

You should attach the event handler properly using Javascript instead (inline handlers are generally considered to be pretty bad practice), and then use `querySelector` to select the other element, from which you can extract its value:

```js
document.querySelector('#invoice_no').addEventListener('change', function() {
  const customerIdVal = document.querySelector('#customer_id').value;
  checkinvoice(this.value, customerIdVal);
});
function checkinvoice(invoiceNo, customerId) {
  console.log('invoiceNo', invoiceNo, 'customerId', customerId);
}
```

```html
<input list="customer_id" id="customer_id"  name="customer_id" >
<input type="text" id="invoice_no" name="invoice_no" >
```